# Grant privileges to set session_replication_role

Tags: postgresql

A script has to import SQL data into an PostgreSQL database. The SQL includes these two lines of code:

```
SET session_replication_role = 'replica';
...
SET session_replication_role = 'origin';
```

The user `xyz` who starts the import doesn't have the power to do this yet. The error `PG::InsufficientPrivilege` gets displayed.

How (with which SQL query) can the user `postgres` grant the user `xyz` the right to set `session_replication_role`? I can't find any documentation about that.

Comment: It seems this is currently only possible with superuser privilege: `Setting this variable requires superuser privilege`, cf. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of PostgreSQL 15+ there is a way to do this:

```
GRANT SET ON PARAMETER session_replication_role TO xyz;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-grant.html

I haven't tried this yet but I bet it works good - in version 14, I used SECURITY DEFINER at the end of a plpgsql procedure with "SET session_replication_role" statements inside of it, and made sure a superuser account was the definer/owner of the procedure - then, any user with EXECUTE privilege can still run it and the parameter setting works as you would hope.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible :-(. See:

> It seems this is currently only possible with superuser privilege:
> Setting this variable requires superuser privilege, cf.
> postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html